# Microsoft edge compatibility on production server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Our web application is working on I.E and chrome but not in Microsoft Edge on Production server. The design is not working.

When I tried it in test/uat environment it works perfectly fine on Microsoft Edge.

I am using MVC5 and IIS7

I also added this to my code

`<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=“IE-Edge”>`

Comment: when you say it's not working... is it loading the site at all? Or some of it looks strange? Any errors?

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using? Is there any error showing in the page/console when it doesn't work in Edge? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? We can't locate the issue with the only description "not working".